# Looking for a JQUERY plugin for conference mapping//planner

Tags: jquery, conference

I was curious if anyone knows of any good examples of plugins that I could use to basically setup a conference planner.

Basically I would have the times running down the size and the rooms running across the top. I'd like for a person to be able to select cells, possibly multiple cells, to reserve those time slots.

Here is an example of a conference map/plan

[image]

The issue with this map is all the conferences cover the same time spans, where the one i'd have could take 15 minutes, 30 minutes, 45 minutes, etc. (I want to set it up in 15 minute intervals)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest taking a look at the fullcalendar control.  http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/ it may require some additional effort to add all the functionality you describe above, but the most important bits are there.